# Is there a method to open a file in erlang under windows and have it locked

Tags: file, erlang, locking

I want to open a file using Erlang but I want this file locked as long as it is opened. Every time I use the below code for opening the file I am able to delete with no problem even though it is still opened by the process.

```
file:open("myfile.txt", [append]),
```

Please note that I can't use the `exclusive` option because it will fail if the file already exists, and I want to keep opening this same file and appending to it, but while it is opened it should be marked as locked and prevent it from being edited or deleted while in use.  I did this with no problem before in both Java, Python and VB, but I tried with Erlang and failed.

Comment: Hey @Sam, please provide a code sample that shows your effort. Please read this as well: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: The code was stated above:
file:open("myfile.txt", [append]),

But while the file is opened I can delete this file.

Comment: Did you try `file:open("my file.txt", [exclusive])`?

Comment: As per my original post the problem with exclusive the file must not exist prior to calling it with exclusive otherwise it gives an error and my logic needs to open to append to it but it must be locked while opened.  However I did delete the file and opened it with exclusive and I was able to delete it from windows while it was opened via an erlang process.